# Error creating localization

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

When creating the first time a localization (Web 8.5+ DXA 2.0 using Java), the localization is found, but we get the following error when creating the config files under the BinaryData folder:

```
    getStaticContent: StaticContentRequestDto(binaryPath=/system/config/_all.json, localizationId=5, localizationPath=/webextras/en/hotel/x/index.html, baseUrl=http://localhost:8080, noMediaCache=false)
15:47:25.549 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE c.s.d.t.c.StaticContentResolver - getStaticContentFile: /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8/8.5.28/libexec/webapps/webextras/BinaryData/5/webextras/en/hotel/x/index.html/system/config/_all.json
```

**Why is creating the URL in this way?** We don't get the page and we get a 404 error.

The _all.json exists in the DB

[image]